# 00’s book about kids heading through door in costume to different universe

Tags: story-identification

I read this book in primary school between 2005-2010. It was about 3 kids/teenagers, I believe who went through a magic door while in costumes and then took on the abilities of those costumes, they traveled to another reality and I know the city was futuristic and I think one of them was dressed as a spaceman… And possibly the other as a cowboy, it was 2 girls and a boy… possibly a YA book. Thanks

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SF&F. There's a great amount of information here, but please review the guidelines for story identification questions and make sure you've covered everything you can. In addition, markdown formatting is supported if you would like to make your post a little more easy to skim for possible answerers.

Comment: The characters are different, but the premise is basically the same as much earlier cartoon named Mr Benn